# Jhipster-registry spring cloud config can not checkout properties from git branch

Tags: bitbucket-server, spring-cloud-config, jhipster-registry

we are using jhipster-registry inside docker and started experiencing the below error since last week. Jhipster-registry could not check out from any branch other than master. Registry startup fails with the below error if a branch other than master is used and works fine with master branch. Below is the docker-compose file. the branch DEVA does exist and the user have access to checkout the repo. this issue started after bitbucketserver upgrade to v5.7.2. We a have separate sys environment where it is working fine. SO i am lost where the issue is.

```
version: '3'
services:
    jhipster-registry:
        image: jhipster/jhipster-registry:v3.2.4
        environment:
            - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod,git
            - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_LABEL=DEVA
            - SECURITY_USER_PASSWORD=admin
            - JHIPSTER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD=admin
            - jhipster_security_authentication_jwt_secret=secret-key
            - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_SERVER_GIT_USERNAME=uname
            - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_SERVER_GIT_PASSWORD=password
            - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_SERVER_GIT_URI=https://username@bitbucketserver/properties.git
            - JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx512m
        ports:
            - "8761:8761"
        volumes:
            - jhipster-registry-app-devb:/tmp/app
        networks:
          - devb

networks:
  devb:
volumes:
  jhipster-registry-app-devb:



main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
deva_jhipster-registry.1.9w17n2x15b41@dfrappd10vl    |
deva_jhipster-registry.1.9w17n2x15b41@dfrappd10vl    | org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.NoSuchLabelException: No such label: DEVA
deva_jhipster-registry.1.9w17n2x15b41@dfrappd10vl    |  at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.refresh(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:188)
deva_jhipster-registry.1.9w17n2x15b41@dfrappd10vl    |  at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.getLocations(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:144)
deva_jhipster-registry.1.9w17n2x15b41@dfrappd10vl    |  at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.getLocations(MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.java:116)
deva_jhipster-registry.1.9w17n2x15b41@dfrappd10vl    |  at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.AbstractScmEnvironmentRepository.findOne(AbstractScmEnvironmentRepository.java:40)
deva_jhipster-registry.1.9w17n2x15b41@dfrappd10vl    |  at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.findOne(MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.java:154)
deva_jhipster-registry.1.9w17n2x15b41@dfrappd10vl    |  at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentRepositoryPropertySourceLocator.locate(EnvironmentRepositoryPropertySourceLocator.java:50)
deva_jhipster-registry.1.9w17n2x15b41@dfrappd10vl    |  at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.initialize(PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.java:93)
deva_jhipster-registry.1.9w17n2x15b41@dfrappd10vl    |  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:567)
deva_jhipster-registry.1.9w17n2x15b41@dfrappd10vl    |  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:338)
deva_jhipster-registry.1.9w17n2x15b41@dfrappd10vl    |  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:301)
deva_jhipster-registry.1.9w17n2x15b41@dfrappd10vl    |  at io.github.jhipster.registry.JHipsterRegistryApp.main(JHipsterRegistryApp.java:75)
deva_jhipster-registry.1.9w17n2x15b41@dfrappd10vl    |  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
deva_jhipster-registry.1.9w17n2x15b41@dfrappd10vl    |  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
deva_jhipster-registry.1.9w17n2x15b41@dfrappd10vl    |  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
deva_jhipster-registry.1.9w17n2x15b41@dfrappd10vl    |  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
deva_jhipster-registry.1.9w17n2x15b41@dfrappd10vl    |  at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
deva_jhipster-registry.1.9w17n2x15b41@dfrappd10vl    |  at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
deva_jhipster-registry.1.9w17n2x15b41@dfrappd10vl    |  at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
deva_jhipster-registry.1.9w17n2x15b41@dfrappd10vl    |  at org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher.main(WarLauncher.java:59)
```